# table reloads everytime I add another column vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I submit a new message which is rendered in the table, but the whole table reloads which creates a flicker effect. This started once I decided to use a table, when I was creating dynamic div I did not have this issue.

**submit method-**

```
const submit = async () => {
  try {
    if (!(message.value.length >= 10)) {
      alert('The message has to be at least 10 characters')
    } else {
      const d: Date = new Date();
      await api.createBlog("test#1234#" + d.getMilliseconds(), message.value).then(
        posts
      )
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error while submitting:', error)
  }
}
```

**The button-**

```
<button type="submit" @click="submit" class="inline-flex justify-center p-2 text-blue-600 rounded-full cursor-pointer hover:bg-blue-100 dark:text-blue-500 dark:hover:bg-gray-600">
  <span class="sr-only">message</span>
</button>
```

What I want is a new row created to populate without the flicker / reload effect.

advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you don't specify the button type, the browser will automatically
> set it to 'reset' or 'submit' which causes the page to reload.

Which indicates `type="submit"` could be the culprit.

So, you can try replacing `type="submit"` with `type="button"`.